cuse_lowlevel and obtain device name
I need to implement my own version of pseudoterminals via cuse (libfuse3). I cannot find information how to obtain device name/path. I need to generate it or get it being generated via cuse. Problem is I prefer to order to generate it to avoid name clashing. Second problem is how to obtain generated name?
My code:
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int ret = -1;
  struct fuse_args args = FUSE_ARGS_INIT(argc, argv);
  struct cuse_info char_dev;
  struct arguments arg;

  if (fuse_parse_cmdline(&args, &opts) != 0) {
        goto end1;
  }

  //start_program(argc-1, &argv[1], pts, comm_ch);
  memset(&char_dev, 0, sizeof(char_dev));
  char_dev.dev_major = 183;
  char_dev.dev_minor = 0;
  char_dev.flags = CUSE_UNRESTRICTED_IOCTL;

  arg.argc = argc;
  arg.argv = argv;

  ret = cuse_lowlevel_main(args.argc, args.argv, &char_dev, &device_operations, &arg);

end1:
    fuse_opt_free_args(&args);
    return ret;
}

